# XML Deserialization For Non-Collection Based Responses

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm using an API to get some informations about web application. I wrote classes to deserialize XML response and added XMLRoot, XMLElement attributes. For XML responses with collection of sub items i can deserialize with using attributes. For example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<time-entries>
   <time-entry>
        //Other sub nodes
   </time-entry>
   <time-entry>
        //Other sub nodes
   </time-entry>
</time-entries>
```

For XML response like above I wrote a TimeEntry class with properties of other attributes of time-entry node. Then I wrote another class with collection of TimeEntry class like below

```
[XmlRoot("time-entries")]
public class TimeEntryResponse
{
    public TimeEntryResponse()
    {

    }

    [XmlElement("time-entry")]
    public List<TimeEntry> TimeEntries { get; set; }

}
```

So, with TimeEntryResponse class I can deserialize XML responses like top of the question.

But I can't deserialize like a response below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<time-totals>
   <total-mins-sum type="integer">382743</total-mins-sum>
   <non-billed-mins-sum type="integer">328988</non-billed-mins-sum>
   <non-billable-hours-sum type="integer">3137.30</non-billable-hours-sum>
</time-totals>
```

I wrote also for this response a TimeTotal class.

```
[XmlRoot("time-totals")]
public class TimeTotal
{
    [XmlElement("total-mins-sum")]
    public double TotalMinsSum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("non-billed-mins-sum")]
    public double NonBilledMinsSum { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("non-billable-hours-sum")]
    public double NonBillableHoursSum { get; set; }
}
```

Then I wrote a response class.

```
public class TimeTotalsResponse : IEntityResponse
{
    public TimeTotalsResponse()
    {

    }

    public TimeTotal TimeTotal { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there is no collection of this response and I don't know which attributes should I add my response class of TimeTotal.

Maybe I can put properties of TimeTotal class directly TimeTotalResponse class. But I will use this class for another deserializations of classes that contaions time-totals node.

Comment: Why not just deserialize directly to the `TimeTotal` class?  It should just work.  Or if you need to also implement `IEntityResponse` have `TimeTotalsResponse` subclass `TimeTotal` rather than encapsulate it.

Comment: @dbc I don't want to serialize TimeTotal class. I need to return a class derived from IEntityResponse because I am doing lots of works on this interface with generic methods. if you mean different thing in your comment could you tell it with code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with out-of-the-box XmlSerialization because your object doesn't map directly to the XML. I can think of 2 methods.

**Method 1:**

Since XML can be deserialized straight to TimeTotal use a simple static method to serialize to TimeTotal first and set it to the property of a newly created TimeTotalsResponse such as:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var response = GetResponse(File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml"));
}

static TimeTotalsResponse GetResponse(string xml)
{
    using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml))
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TimeTotal));
        return new TimeTotalsResponse() { TimeTotal = (TimeTotal)ser.Deserialize(reader) };
    }
}
```

**Method 2:** 
Customize the serialization by writing your own XmlSerializer such as:

```
public class TimeTotalsResponseSerializer : IXmlSerializable
{
    public TimeTotalsResponse Response { get; set; }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        Response = new TimeTotalsResponse();
        Response.TimeTotal = new TimeTotal();

        reader.ReadToDescendant("total-mins-sum");
        Response.TimeTotal.TotalMinsSum = reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
        Response.TimeTotal.NonBilledMinsSum = reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
        Response.TimeTotal.NonBillableHoursSum = reader.ReadElementContentAsDouble();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
    }
}
```

and the usage would be;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings()
    {
        IgnoreWhitespace = true
    };

    string xml = File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml");
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), settings))
    {
        var ser = new TimeTotalsResponseSerializer();
        ser.ReadXml(reader);
        var response = ser.Response;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way of seeing the issue is to serialized the data.  See code below.  Look at the two XML files produced for : xsi:type="TimeEntries" and xsi:type="TimeTotalsResponse"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test2.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TimeEntries timeEntries = new TimeEntries()
            {
                timeEntry = new List<TimeEntry>() {
                    new TimeEntry() {},
                    new TimeEntry() {},
                    new TimeEntry() {}
                }
            };
            TimeTotalsResponse timeTotals = new TimeTotalsResponse()
            {
                TotalMinsSum = new TypeInteger() { _type = "integer", _value = 382743 },
                NonBilledMinsSum = new TypeInteger() { _type = "integer", _value = 328988 },
                NonBillableHoursSum = new TypeInteger() { _type = "integer", _value = 3137.30 }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TimeEntryResponse));

            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME1);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, timeEntries);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();

            writer = new StreamWriter(FILENAME2);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, timeTotals);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            writer.Dispose();


        }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(TimeEntries))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(TimeTotalsResponse))]
    [Serializable]
    public class TimeEntryResponse
    {

    }
    [XmlRoot("time-entries")]
    public class TimeEntries : TimeEntryResponse
    {
        [XmlElement("time-entry")]
        public List<TimeEntry> timeEntry { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlRoot("time-entry")]
    public class TimeEntry
    {
    }
    [XmlRoot("time-totals")]
    public class TimeTotalsResponse : TimeEntryResponse
    {

        [XmlElement("total-mins-sum")]
        public TypeInteger  TotalMinsSum { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("non-billed-mins-sum")]
        public TypeInteger NonBilledMinsSum { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("non-billable-hours-sum")]
        public TypeInteger NonBillableHoursSum { get; set; }
    }
    public class TypeInteger
    {
        [XmlAttribute("type")]
        public string _type { get; set; }
        [XmlText]
        public double _value { get; set; }
    }
}
​
```